# With GraphQL is it possible to replace the websocket used for subscription with a message-based approach (e.g. MQ)

Tags: graphql, message-queue, apollo-server

Whereas the corporate environment I am working in accepts the use of http(s) based request response patterns, which is OK for GraphQL Query and Mutation, they have issues with the use of websockets as needed for GraphQL Subscription and would prefer that the subscription is routed via IBM MQ.

Does anyone have any experience with this? I am thinking of using Apollo Server to serve up the GraphQL interface. Perhaps there is a front-end subscription solution that can be plugged in using IBM MQ? The back end data sources are Oracle databases.

Comment: This has nothing to do with IBM MQ, so you should remove the ibm-mq tag.

Comment: Actually, I was lazy in my wording. Concretely, it does concern IBM MQ

Answer (score 0):

Message queues are usually used to communicate between services while web sockets are how browsers can communicate with the server over a constant socket. This allows the server to send data to the client when a new event of a subscription arrived (classically browsers only supported "pull" and could only receive data when they asked for it). Browsers don't implement the MQ protocols you would need to directly subscribe to the MQ itself. I am not an expert on MQs but what is usually done is there is a subscription server that connects to the client via web socket. The subscription service then itself subscribes to the message queue and notifies relevant clients about their subscribed events. You can easily scale the subscription servers horizontally when you need additional resources.

Comment: Thanks. What I was wondering was whether one could replace the websocket part of the GraphQL server receive the subscription via either http or an MQ message, with the results being sent out to another MQ queue